# JAVA: How can I access to members of each classes?

Tags: java

How can I access to members of each classes?

I have class Dog and Cat. They have different member variable of class.
I try to create one function "CommUtil.display()" to access many classes (Dog or Cat) and display all members of class.

I try to access from mainClass to access Dog or Cat class.
but it can't.

Anyone can help will be appreciated.

I have made an example below:

```
    class Dog {
        private String name = null;
        private String weight  = null;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getWeight() {
            return weight;
        }
        public void setWeight(String weight) {
            this.weight = weight;
        }
    }


    class Cat {
        private String name = null;
        private String age = null;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getAge() {
            return age;
        }
        public void setAge(String age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

    }


    class commUtil {
        //TODO: output members of class
        public void display (Object obj){
            //Question: How to access members of each classes?
            //code here...






        }

    }


    class mainClass {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Dog d = new Dog();
            commUtil.display(d);

            or 

            Cat c = new Cat();
            commUtil.display(c);
        }
    }

In case 1: 
Dog d = new Dog();
d.setName("Lion");
d.setWeight("2Kg");
commUtil.display(d);

It will display Name and Weight of Dog

In case 2: 
Cat c = new Cat();
c.setName("MiMi");
c.setAge("1");
commUtil.display(c);

It will display Name and Age of Cat
```

Comment: Why not use the accessor/getter methods declared in each class?

Comment: how to access it?

Comment: Well since the parameter is of type `Object`, you’ll need to do an `instanceof` check and some casting.

Comment: But commUtil I have made, it's just common class.
I can't check it inside directly
And there are many classes will call commUtil.display().

Should I need to create abstract class or interface to solve it?

Comment: What are you trying to display exactly?

Comment: `private name = null;` -- this is not valid Java. Have you actually tried to compile this?

Comment: In case 1: 
Dog d = new Dog();
d.setName("Lion");
d.setWeight("2Kg");
commUtil.display(d);

It will display Name and Weight of Dog

In case 2: 
Cat c = new Cat();
c.setName("MiMi");
c.setAge("1");
commUtil.display(c);

It will display Name and Age of Cat

Comment: @JimGarrison, sorry I have modified.

Comment: @Decode You could always just override `toString()` then display  its return value in `display()`.

Comment: @Logan: I can get only field name or method name, but I can't get value :/

Comment: @Decode What do you mean? If you override `toString()` you can access the field values while you’re declaring the method. Then you can call it in `display()`. Every object has a `toString()` method.

Comment: for field names you can use `Field[] f=type.getClass().getDeclaredFields();` to get values of fields you can use `getters`

Comment: @Deadpool To get the value of the field, the `get()` method will need to be used.

Comment: thank you @Logan updated code, you get field and value

Comment: @Deadpool No problem!

Comment: Can it uses abstract or interface class to solve this problem?
Cos in reality It's not just display data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what inheritance is for, so you would make an `abstract` super class possibly called `Animal` in this case and then `Dog` and `Cat` would extend that class as subclasses. [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-java/) is a fairly simple tutorial about inheritance.

```
public abstract class Animal {

    /** Common name property for all animals */
    private String name;

    /** Common age property for all animals */
    private int age;

    public Animal(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
         return name;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age= age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
         return age;
    }

    /** 
    * Abstract method that will need to be implemented 
    * by a concrete class that inherits from this abstract class
    */
    public abstract String getInfo();

    public abstract String speak();

    public abstract String getType();
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    
     /*
     Any Dog specific properties would also go in here
     */       

    private boolean isPedigree = false;

    /** Class Constructor */
    public Dog(String name, int age, boolean isPedigree) {
        super(name, age);
        this.isPedigree = isPedigree;
    }

    public boolean isPedigree() {
        return isPedigree;
    }

    @Override
    public String getInfo() {
        return "I am a Dog named " + name + " and I am " + age + " years old.";
    }

    @Override
    public String speak() {
        return "WOOF";
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return Dog.class.getSimpleName();
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal() {
     
     /*
     Any Cat specific properties would also go in here
     */

     /** Class Constructor */
    public Cat(String name, int age) {
        super(name, age);
    }

    @Override
    public String getInfo() {
        return "I am a " + getType() + named " + name + " and I am " + age + " years old.";
    }

    @Override
    public String speak() {
        return "meow";
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return Cat.class.getSimpleName();
    }
}

public class MyMainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         Just creating a random array to show that
         any animal whether Dog or Cat can be placed into
         this array as they inherit from Animal
        */
        List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();

        animals.add(new Dog("James", 5, true));
        animals.add(new Cat("Treacle", 2));

        for (Animal animal : animals) {
            display(animal);
            if (animal instanceof Dog) {
                boolean isPedigree = ((Dog) animal).isPedigree();
                System.out.println("Q: Am I a Pedigree? A: " + String.valueOf(isPedigree));
            }
        }
    }

    private void display(Animal animal) {
        System.out.println("I'm an animal of type " + animal.getType() + " and I can say " + animal.speak());
        System.out.println(animal.getInfo());
    }
}
```

Our output would be:

> I'm an animal of type Dog and I can say WOOF
>
> I am a Dog named James and I am 5 years old.
>
> Q: Am I a Pedigree? A: true
>
> I'm an animal of type Cat and I can say meow
>
> I am a Cat named Treacle and I am 2 years old.

This answer shows simple [inheritance](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-java/) and [polymorphism](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm). This of the backbone of OOP (Object Orientated Programming) and when learning Java will be the essential basics you will need to learn and understand.

In my example `getInfo()` could actually just be a method in Animal as there is nothing specific it is doing per subclass. You could also move `display` into the `Animal` abstract class if you which, I only placed it here for the example.

There is no need for any `CommonUtils` class or anything like that here, everything you want can be done by simply learning about inheritance.

What we are saying in this example is `Cat` and `Dog` are `Animals` they inherit all the characteristics of any `Animal`. What you can't do though is create a random `Animal` object like `Animal animal = new Animal("Paul", 4);`, the `Animal` has to be of some sort of type whether that is of type `Dog`, `Cat` or some other Subclass of `Animal` you create (i.e. `Bird`, `Fish` or even `Human`).

Comment: In case Class Dog has different member variable from Class Cat.
What should I do?

Comment: @Decode I've amended my code to include the property on the class Dog with isPedigree (Property for example only) then I've amended the for loop to check if animal is instance of Dog and if so it will print out whether it is a pedigree. Note as well I have amended the constructor for Dog so it takes in 3 arguments instead of 2 like the Cat class.

Answer (score 4):

If the code can still change, you may be able to use java interface.  The idea is that both Dog and Cat implements a common interface for output display.  In practice though, it will have the same result as modifying toString() like the other comments already covered. Anyway, here is an example:

```
public interface AnimalInfo {
    public String getInfo();
}
```

and then both `Dog` and `Cat` classes can implements this interface.

```
class Dog implements AnimalInfo {
...

public String getInfo() {
    return "name="+name+", weight="+weight;
}

class Cat implements AnimalInfo {
...

public String getInfo() {
    return "name="+name+", age="+age;
}
```

and then inside commUtil the argument can use the interface type `AnimalInfo`

```
public void display (AnimalInfo animal){
    System.out.println("It will display " + 
    animal.getInfo() + " of " + animal.getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java reflection to get all fields from object, below is the example, you can achieve this by `T` parameter method in utility class

```
public class ArrayMain {

int x=10; String name="anil";
public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

    ArrayMain m = new ArrayMain();
     m1(m);     
     SomeOther o = new SomeOther();
     m1(o);
}   
public int getX() {
    return x;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
static <T> void m1(T type) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field[] f=type.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    for(Field f1:f) {
        System.out.println(f1.getName());
        System.out.println(f1.get(type));
    }
}

 }
```

Comment: I have tried it. But I can't get value . How to do it?

Comment: @Decode You can look at the documentation for the `Field` class [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html).

Comment: updated code you can try this, if you want values you can use getters

Answer (score 0):

You can have the CommonUtil class as shown below. Also, make the display method static as you are trying to access it using class name.

```
class CommUtil {
    //TODO: output members of class
    public static void display (Object obj){
        //Question: How to access members of each classes?
        //code here...

        if(obj instanceof Dog) {

            System.out.println(((Dog) obj).getName());
            System.out.println(((Dog) obj).getWeight());

        }
    }

}
```

But as mentioned in the comments you can just override toString() method inside every class and display objects for all those classes.

```
public String toString() {
        return "Cat [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }
```

Comment: It's good to override method toString().
Can I  use abstract or interface class to solve this problem?
If can, Can you show me the way?

Comment: @Decode I don't think you can use interfaces as they cannot have instance variables. But you can use abstract class. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/51721737/6407858 answer

Answer (score -1):

Check if the object is an instance of `Cat` or `Dog` using the `instanceof` operator. Then you must perform a cast to access the object’s getter methods.

```
if(obj instanceof Cat){
    Cat cat = ((Cat) obj);

    System.out.println(cat.getName());
}
```

Comment: Actually I can't check it directly inside commUtil class.